# Can't delete a heap instance of my custom class (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, heap-memory, destructor

Here's what I've got:

```
class MyClass {
    int holder;
public:
    MyClass() {
        holder = 5;
    }
};
```

---

```
template<class T>
class First {
    std::vector<T> items;
public:
    First() {
        T* tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            tmp = new T();
            items.push_back(*tmp);
        }
    };
    ~First() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            delete items.at(i);
        }
    };
};
```

---

```
class Second {
    std::vector<std::deque<First<MyClass>>> items;
public:
    Second() {
        std::deque<First<MyClass>>* tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tmp = new std::deque<First<MyClass>>;
            items.push_back(*tmp);
        }   
    };
    ~Second() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < items.at(i).size(); j++) {
                delete items.at(i).at(j); // this deletes the "First" instances
            }
            delete items.at(i); // this deletes the deque
        }
    };
};
```

---

In my `main`, I'm create an instance of `Second` and adding `First` instances to it (through methods that aren't included). At the end of `main`, I delete the instance of `Second`, which should delete all the instances of `First` and the `deques`. However, I'm getting the following errors:

```
error: cannot delete expression of type 'value_type' (aka 'MyClass')
error: cannot delete expression of type 'value_type' (aka 'First<MyClass>')
error: cannot delete expression of type 'value_type' (aka 'std::deque<First<MyClass>>')
```

Essentially, all my `delete` commands are throwing errors. What am I missing here? I need to manually implement a destructor because I created a bunch of stuff on the heap - correct?

Comment: Why not use smart pointers?

Comment: In First class, you do not need any new or delete. `items.push_back(T());` is sufficient to add a new T to the vector. The vector automatically deletes the elements it contains.

Comment: @Marcin That's not a good suggestion as there should be NO pointers.

Comment: You're creating objects on the heap, then pushing **copies** of those objects into a vector, then leaking the heap objects, then trying to delete the copies (but doing it wrong). Don't do that. it's undefined behaviour and disgusting

Comment: You may have heard C++ is not a garbage-collected language and so you need to delete everything manually. You heard wrong. At least the second part, anyway.

Comment: That code is equivalent to: `T* t = new T(); T copy = *t; delete copy;` ... I hope seeing it in that form shows how clearly wrong it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are never storing the result of the `new` expression. Your code should perhaps look like this:

```
First() {
    T* tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tmp = new T();
        items.push_back(*tmp);
        delete tmp;              // result of "new" is still accessible here
    }
}

~First() { }
```

Or like this:

```
First() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        items.push_back(T());
    }
}
```

Or just like this:

```
First() : items(20) {}
```

Comment: Alright I think I get it now. Obviously your way is much better (doesn't need the heap). However, before I was pushing copies into the vector right? Is it even possible for an object in the heap to be "part of" a structure that isn't in the heap (I hope I'm asking the question clearly).

Comment: @maxmackie: No. Objects consist of a contiguous chunk of memory and have a fixed size. You can of course stick pointers to other parts of memory into an object, but then only the pointer is part of the object, not the pointee.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I definitely wasn't thinking enough when writing this :)